# Is there a limit to the number of enemies spawned during the timed waves of the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During several of the waves in the multiplayer component of Mass Effect 3, the players are tasked with shutting down a number of stationary objectives throughout the level in a set time limit instead of just killing all of the enemies in the wave. When I played on bronze, there were four objectives that had to be shut down in four minutes (I'm not sure if this varies by difficulty or not).

**During this type of wave, has anyone determined whether enemies spawn indefinitely until the objectives are disabled?** It would be nice to know whether thinning out the enemies first is a good strategy, or whether it's best to rush to the objectives since the enemies will keep replenishing.

Comment: I don't think the enemies replenish, but I admit I have no real data to back that up. It's mostly a moot point anyway since the most profitable tactic tends to be shooting your way to each objective point and then taking it as fast as possible to max out the time bonus.

Comment: My anecdotal evidence says they do replenish. As a Krogan solder, the rest of my team went down. I spent most of the time limit clearing rooms of enemies, only to return to a room I had cleared to find it full of enemies again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for Bronze rankings. For this type of mission depending on which wave it is you will get stronger monsters that spawn plus the trash monsters. After the stronger monsters are dead, the trash monsters will never stop spawning, they will also continue to spawn in the same area until your team moves to a different area or completes one of the 4 disarmings.

I have done this a few times with reapers as an enemy, I forgot which wave, but there was 2 banshees and 2 brutes and 3 or 4 ravagers. After all those enemies were dead the only monsters that continued to spawn were cannibals and maruder and rarely a few husks would come running.

I forgot the numbers now and dont have it in front of me at work, but I think 8 enemies can spawn at once and only a maxium of 2 spawn points at a time. So from what I have seen, no facts behind this. So if you know where current spawn point is you can run the backways around the map as they head to your last location (as long as you dont shoot) and than can get the next objective and never have to shoot at the trash, and until you kill the trash more wont spawn.

But I have stood in the same spot for 4 minutes with a sniper rifle and let them run down the hallway and killed 20-30 monsters in the 4 minutes because spawn point didnt change because I did not move. 4 minutes ended, my mission ended, but got like 20k score.

Answer (score 7):

They do replenish.  Not only that but they seem to replenish the same enemies, so if you kill four atlases, four more atlases respawn (waste of time).  Weaker enemies (or tough enemies that have you pinned down), it's a good idea to clear one wave and then move to the objective.  If they are spawning between you and the objective, forget about it, just run for it.  Generally a good idea to flank safely around them though: while you're doing so the respawns may shift to a more manageable location.

Comment: this is correct.  Enemies do replenish, but only the base level enemies.  The upper tiers have a limit per wave, once they reach that limit per wave, they no longer appear

Answer (score 1):

Fighting Reapers on Silver, 4 Banshees spawned in succession, after the four banshees were dead none spawned for the remaining minutes or so.  The mooks kept respawning but none of the mini boss types.